# ValueError when loading a text classification model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am getting an error when I try to load the model with `tf.keras.models.load_model()` and I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: The mask that was passed in was tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("Placeholder_2:0", shape=(None,), dtype=bool), 
row_splits=Tensor("Placeholder_3:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64))
and cannot be applied to RaggedTensor inputs. 
Please make sure that there is no mask passed in by upstream layers.
```

---

Following is my model architecture

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    encoder,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()),output_dim=64,mask_zero=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences = True),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(7)
])
```

Encoding Layer:

```
encoder = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE)
```

---

The model was saved with: `model.save(PATH)`

I am loading the model from a different notebook. Can I get some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved this by removing the `mask_zero=True` attribute from the embedding layer, however, I'm not sure why this works and why it did not work with `mask_zero=True`. It would be helpful if someone can tell me the reason.